# Setting cookie and incrementing each time a function is run

Tags: jquery, var

Im using js-cookie.js to set a cookie on a button click. No issue there. I need to check to see if the cookie is set and increment a var each time the check is run. How do I increment "x" the second time the function is run and check for both the cookie and x value?

```
Cookies.get('NTAD');
var x ="0";
$(function(){
        if(Cookies.get('NTAD') == 'true') {
        $.getScript('/js/adroll.js');
    } else if(Cookies.get('NTAD') != 'true' && (x = '0')) {
        //here is where I fade in a banner with "Yes"(sets cookie) and "No" button
        //need to increment var x here
        alert(x);
        x="1"
    } else if(Cookies.get('NTAD') != 'true' && (x = '1')){
        //second time through, x should = 1 from above and just show banner but not fade
        alert(x);
    }
});
```

Comment: It looks like your If logic is setting X  to '0' (x = '0') instead of comparing to to '0' (x == '0')

Comment: I changed the If logic to (x == '0') but it still alerts "0" for the value but console shows the value as 1.